# I can't get rows have NULL on all rows for column zfeaturekey based on zplid and code type?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I work with SQL Server 2012. I have an issue I can't get rows from table `#gen` when it has Null only on all rows on `zfeaturekey` field based on `zplid` and `codetypeid`.

I need to get rows that have NULL only on all rows ON `zfeaturekey`, but must be same `codetypeid` and same `zplid` .

```
CREATE TABLE #gen
(
    CodeTypeId int,
    Zplid  int,
    Zfeaturekey nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #gen 
VALUES 
  (854838, 25820, NULL),
  (849774, 25820, NULL),
  (849774, 25820, NULL),
  (849774, 25820, NULL),
  (849774, 25820, NULL),
  (987431, 26777, NULL),
  (987431, 26777, 1502280005),
  (987431, 26777, 1502290001)
```

Output:

```
 CodeTypeId       Zplid    Zfeaturekey
 -------------------------------------
 854838            25820    NULL
 849774            25820    NULL
 849774            25820    NULL
 849774            25820    NULL
 849774            25820    NULL
```

This is the result I need:

```
 CodeTypeId      Zplid      COUNT
 ---------------------------------
 854838          25820        1
 849774          25820        4
```

I will not take `zplid = 26777` because it has `Null` and values as 1502280005 on another rows.

I need to select where feature is NULL on all rows by `zplid` and `codetypeid` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `group by` and `having`.

```
Select codetypeid, zplid, count(1) as cnt
From t
Group by codetypeid, zplid
Having count(zfeaturekey) = 0
```